# update User attr, ruby claiming for its password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

why every time that i retrieve an existent User and try to update its email, ruby throws an exception claiming for its password.

anyone got the same issue?

**UserModel**

```
    attr_accessible   :nome, :sobrenome, :email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation, :genero,
                    :endereco, :numero, :bairro, :complemento, :cidade, :estado, :cep



  has_secure_password

  before_create {generate_token(:auth_token)}

  attr_accessor :password
 email_regex = /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i



  validates_presence_of :nome, :sobrenome, :genero, :email, :password, :on => :create 


  validates :email, :format => {:with => email_regex},
                    :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false }


  validates :password, :length => {:within=> 6..60},
                       :confirmation => true


  validates :email, :confirmation => true,
                    :on => :update
```

Comment: password lenght is not an exception. Please add a stacktrace to the question. It's difficult to understand what it's going wrong this way.

Comment: OK luca,  the code is not breaking, in fact everything is working fine, the only problem is that every time I'll update any user attribute gives an error asking for the password length. even if i try to update the email. anyway thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is how i handled this problem.

```
validates_presence_of :password,  :on => :create

 validates :password, :length => {:within=> 6..60},
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :if => :is_password_validation_needed?

private 

       def is_password_validation_needed? 
         new_record? || password
       end
```

Comment: Ok so yoi don't need the validation on create anymore

Comment: i still need it, but a don`t why when a i go update other fields sill requesting the password. even stating presence on create and update was requesting every time.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly demand the password on update:

```
 validates :password,
           :presence => true,
           :on => :update,
```

Your rules are not well written. take some advice here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: thank you very much but in that case i had to create a method.